# OpenAPI and CLI generators tools for server stubs

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm familiar with RESTful APIs, however, I'm new to Swagger and Open API. I'd like to clarify the role of tools such as openapi-generator-cli and how to make the best use of these tools.

Using the latest specification for [OpenAPI](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md), it's clear 
how to design the API.  For example, I can write my api in a .yml file. In my case, I'm using Java and SpringBoot as my language and I'm interested in using the [open-generator-cli](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/wiki/Server-stub-generator-HOWTO#java-springboot) to create a server stub from the .yml file.

I can then point my browser to http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html#/.  Other than providing, nice documentation which shows the endpoints, the parameters, model, responses and curl request what other value does a server-stub provide? Is it common to take the server code and adapt it into a production codebase? And then as the API changes, the whole steps can be repeated more easily?